# OpenCV inpainting function

Tags: opencv, gimp

I've been using recently the built-in fuction of opencv for inpainting.
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/photo/doc/inpainting.html

I have to say that the results were very poor when the areas to inpaint were big... I guess these functions are mean just for removing scartes and similar.
I found that in Gimp [Resynthesizer](http://www.logarithmic.net/pfh/resynthesizer) works perfecly for my purposes. Is there any implementation of this algorithm or similar in OpenCV? I found strange that nobody has implemented an opencv version for such an interesting function!

Comment: opencv is no painting/graphics library. Such a feature might be interesting for computer vision, too, but probably has no priority.

Comment: Any solution yet?

Comment: Any solution yet?

Comment: No that I know... Srry!